# ngFor over array or observable does not update html values angular 8

Tags: html, arrays, angular, observable, watch

I have an angular service which connects with the BE and gets a stream of events and returns an Observable.

```
streamObjArray:StreamObj[] = [];

getStream() : Observable<Array<StreamObj>> {
...
return new Observable((observer) => {
  let eventSource = new EventSource(this.serverStreamUrl);
  eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
    ... 
    observer.next(this.streamObjArray);
  };
  eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
    ...
 });
}
```

In my component I use this service and have tried 2 approaches, one exposing the Observable return type from the service method directly to the component:

```
...
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
providers: [AppService],
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
...
  streamObs: Observable<StreamObj[]>;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  connectStream(): void {
    console.log("init");
    this.streamObs = this.appService.getStream();

    // need to use the setInterval call or FE html doesn't update
    setInterval(() => this.streamObs, 1000);
  }
}
```

for this approach the html uses a `*ngFor` with an async pipe :

```
<tr *ngFor="let streamObj of streamObs | async">
 ...
{{streamObj.attr1}}
</tr>
```

I've also tried another approach subscribing to it and assigning the value to an array:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
providers: [AppService],
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

subscription: Subscription;
streamList: StreamObj[];

constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

connectStream(): void {
  this.subscription = this.appService.getStream()
    .subscribe((localStream => this.streamList = localStream));

  // next line required to update table in html Front End
  // otherwise the table never updates.
  setInterval(() => this.streamList, 1000);
 }
}
```

for this approach the html uses a `*ngFor` without any pipes:

```
<tr *ngFor="let streamObj of streamList">
 ...
{{streamObj.attr1}}
</tr>
```

Both approaches work only if I constantly reference the attribute in a setInterval function call as explained in the code and code comment above, which shouldn't be necessary. What am I missing?

Comment: 1. Please check `this.streamObj` in your `getStream` method is an array. Make sure when you do `observer.next()`, you passing an array of `StreamObj`? 2. In your component in the first approach, I do not see `streamList` which you are using in the template, Do you mean `streamObs` instead? There could be a better way to return observable instead of `new Observable(`... Bottom line is when you do the `next` then make sure you pass an array of `StreamObj` because this is what you expect in template [i.e. ngFor]

Comment: Thank you for questioning, I added some more code to make it clear how I am assigning the array when calling `.next()`. I am wondering should I try passing a single streamObj to next and update the array in component instead? I will try that.

Comment: It is fine to pass the array in `next`. Can you try passing the clone of the array like this - `observer.next([...this.streamObjArray])`

Comment: Will do, but wouldn't this have a performance issue when the array strats to grow? This array might end up with up to around 5K items.

Comment: yes, if its 5K length then that could be the issue. I was not aware if your array could be too big. As you mentioned, You can take the component approach as well. Push you new streamObj in array in the component.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly I got same results when using the spread operator as you suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195954/discussion-between-user2216584-and-groo).

Comment: can you check in your first approach if you really have any values:
this.streamObs = this.appService.getStream().pipe(tap(value => console.log(value))).

Comment: hi, thanks. I've checked and the values are there.. that's actually also clear when setInterval is added as it all works.. and setInterval is not doing anything only "touching" i.e -`setInterval(() => this.streamList, 1000);`  the array reference every second.. and then the update "gets noticed" and FE updates.